# Why is this cin validation not working on other file while work only on one file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to use this cin validation on every input on my project, mostly for 'choosing' activity.

```
if (cin.fail()) { // Failed to parse input correctly
    cin.clear(); // Clear the internal flags
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // Ignore the rest of the buffer
}
```

This code works only on one file which is the Menu.cpp, but not Conference.cpp. It shows one error which is 'E0040 expected an identifier' and it highlighted the max() syntax. I also try to copy the code from Menu.cpp to Conference.cpp but still it shows the same error on Conference.cpp. I don't know what causes the error.

Menu.h

```
#pragma once
class Menu
{
public:
    Menu();
    void mainmenu();
    void dataregmenu();
    ~Menu();
};
```

Menu.cpp

```
#include "Menu.h"
#include "Menu_controller.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Menu::Menu()
{
    
}

void Menu::mainmenu()
{
    int choose;

    cout << "-----Conference Vault----- \n\n";
    cout << "1. Data Registration \n";
    cout << "2. Conference \n";
    cout << "3. Report \n\n";
    cout << "Choose: ";

    cin >> choose;

    if (cin.fail()) { // Failed to parse input correctly
        cin.clear(); // Clear the internal flags
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // Ignore the rest of the buffer
    }

    new Menu_controller(choose);
}

void Menu::dataregmenu()
{
    int choose;

    cout << "-----Data Registration----- \n\n";
    cout << "1. ADUN \n";
    cout << "2. Department \n\n";
    cout << "3. Back \n\n";
    cout << "Choose: ";

    cin >> choose;

    if (cin.fail()) { // Failed to parse input correctly
        cin.clear(); // Clear the internal flags
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // Ignore the rest of the buffer
    }

    
}

Menu::~Menu()
{
}
```

Conference.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Conference
{
public:
    Conference();
    void conferencemenu();
    void addconference();
    ~Conference();
};
```

Conference.cpp

```
#include "Conference.h"
#include "Conference_controller.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Conference::Conference()
{
    
}

void Conference::conferencemenu()
{
    int choose;

    cout << "Choose what to do: \n\n";
    cout << "1. Add new conference \n";
    cout << "2. Find conference \n\n";
    cout << "3. Back \n\n";
    cout << "Choose: ";

    cin >> choose;

    if (cin.fail()) { // Failed to parse input correctly
        cin.clear(); // Clear the internal flags
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // Ignore the rest of the buffer
    }

    new Conference_controller(choose);
}

void Conference::addconference()
{
    string year, month, number;
    Conference_controller conf;

    cout << "-----New Conference----- \n\n\n";
    cout << "Please fill in the required fields: \n\n";
    cout << "Year: ";
    cin >> year;
    cout << "Month: ";
    cin >> month;
    cout << "Number: ";
    cin >> number;

    conf.addconference(year, month, number);
}

Conference::~Conference()
{
}
```

Comment: Please read about the [mcve]. (And read about appropriate use of `new` in your favourite C++ book.)

Comment: The failing file indirectly includes a `max` macro, most likely through the Windows SDK.

Comment: On that note, always compile your C++ Windows code with NOMINMAX defined. You're welcome. You're also using `std::numeric_limits`, but not including `<limits>` which is *required* to be standard-conformant.